# need some example of spl token or sol transfer

Tags: solana-program, spl-token, anchor-spl

I stored the amount and Pubkey inside my smart contract.
I tried transferring to that pubkey, but the function is asking AccountInfo.
I tried instantiating Accountinfo but I don't know other fields except few pubkey, isSigner, isWritable, etc.
please provide me a solution for this.

Comment: please provide some code you've written

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can I transfer sol using pubkey?](https://solana.stackexchange.com/questions/1632/can-i-transfer-sol-using-pubkey)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a common misconception when first starting with Solana development.

Anytime you're dealing with an account whose state you're trying to read or write, what you want is not the *pubkey*, but the *account*. In Anchor this type is notated as an `AccountInfo<'info>`.

So where you specify "to" in your transfer CPI, you can't simply give it a pubkey. You need to give it an `AccountInfo<'info>`.

So where do you get these things? From your `ctx` that comes in as an argument to your instruction handler. Which means that in addition to simply having the pubkey in your program logic, you need to pass that pubkey into your instruction. Which in turn means you should have it as a field in your `#[derive(Accounts)]` struct.